# Perl script from Ubuntu doesn't run on Debian

Tags: shell-script, debian, ubuntu, perl

I have a Perl script which I created on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It's okay and works. I took this script on another machine with Debian on it. It doesn't run with:

```
./my_script.pl
```

This gave me: `./my_script.pl Command not found`, although it works with

```
perl my_script.pl
```

Why? Attributes are `-rwx--x--x`, so everything should be ok.
My shebang is: `#!/bin/perl`

Comment: Does `/bin/perl` exist? You might want to use `#!/usr/bin/env perl`

Comment: I can't add comment. `#!/usr/bin/env perl` - doesn't help me. Script with my shebang works on ubuntu. Sir with debian told me "paths, variables and shebang doesn't matter. But this error indicates that you work on ubuntu" - what's going on?

Comment: @glennjackman That's very lousy advice. Any perl script will have to account for whatever perl version a user may have in their path, instead of just the regular one from the distro. And also creates ample opportunities for abusing any naive assumptions made in the script. Just using `#! /usr/bin/perl` instead of `#! /bin/perl` (as in Stephen Kitt's answer) is the way to go.

Comment: That Debian user is probably using a newer versions of Debian, where (exactly as in your Ubuntu) `/bin/perl` works because `/bin` is a symbolic link to `usr/bin`, which was not the case in older versions. Just change the `#!/bin/perl` to `#!/usr/bin/perl` and it will work everywhere.

Comment: @OskarSkog `#!/usr/bin/env perl -arg` does NOT work, because it will try to run `perl -arg` as a single command, instead of `perl` with `-arg` as its first argument. That, in addition to I've said [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617022/perl-script-from-ubuntu-doesnt-run-on-debian#comment1154069_617022). And, also, the `/usr/bin/env` is completely non-standard, even if happens to exist on most systems.

Comment: @glennjackman and, of course `#! /usr/bin/perl/env perl --` (or using any extra argument with the interpreter, like `-p` or `-C`) will not work at all, unless you're making the kludge even worse with non-portable `env` switches.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/356625)

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl - I proposed this Debian user before I asked, No. It doesn't work for him :/ He said "It's not fault caused by: path,shebang etc. But this indicates you work on ubuntu".

Comment: @JMKane change the permissions of the script to 0755 (`-rwxr-xr-x`) instead of 0711 (`-rwx--x--x`), executable *scripts* also need to be *readable* by the user who execute them.

Comment: @user414777 Debian user said that it's not caused by perm. He also checked 777.

Comment: The it's probable that the perl interpreter itself is broken. Does it work if you call it `/usr/bin/perl ./my_script` instead of just `perl ./my_script`? You have to also check if the script is not using windows-style line terminators (CR/LF) -- though the error message doesn't suggest that (check with `cat -v ./my_script | sed 1q` -- you will see a `^M` at the end).

Comment: @JMKane please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts for help on merging your accounts.

Answer (score 9):

The correct shebang for Perl scripts on Debian is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

This will work Ubuntu, Debian, and many other distributions and Unix-like systems.

`/bin/perl` works on your Ubuntu system because [it has merged a number of directories “shared” between `/` and `/usr`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/Specs/Quantal/UsrMerge), including `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, so `/usr/bin/perl` is also available as `/bin/perl`.

Comment: Did Ubuntu really merged `/usr` and `/`, or just `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, and `/lib*` and `/usr/lib*`?

Comment: @user414777 it’s known as [UsrMerge](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/Specs/Quantal/UsrMerge) (and [in Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge)), but yes, it’s not a full merge — `/bin`, `/sbin`, and `/lib*` point to their equivalents under `/usr`. I’ll clarify that in the answer.

Comment: FYI: as gathered from [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617022/perl-script-from-ubuntu-doesnt-run-on-debian/617068#comment1154103_617025), the user's problem doesn't seem to be related to the `/bin/perl` path not existing. My guess is that it's another instance of the "she-bang line terminated by CR/LF" problem.

Answer (score 1):

> `./my_script.pl` => `Command not found`
> although it works with `perl my_script.pl`

That suggests that your script is using Windows-style `CR/LF` line terminators or it may be starting with a UTF-8 "BOM" signature.

You can check if that's the case with

```
cat -v ./my_script | sed 1q
```

and look for a `^M` (carriage-return) at the end, or `M-oM-;M-?` at the beginning.

Example:

```
$ cat ./script
#! /usr/bin/perl
print "hello\n"

$ perl ./script
hello

$ ./script
/bin/sh: 1: ./script: not found

$ cat -v ./script
#! /usr/bin/perl^M
print "hello\n"^M
```

Bash, but not dash or most other programs will use a more helpful error message, like `/usr/bin/perl^M: bad interpreter`.

Notice that perl itself doesn't care about carriage-returns in scripts; it's treating them exactly like any other white space character:

```
$ cat ./foo
print "hello\n"

$ perl ./foo
LOL

$ cat -v ./foo
print "LOL\n";^M#^Mprint "hello\n"
```

---

> Attributes are `-rwx--x--x`, so everything should be ok.

That's also generally not OK. Such a script will only be usable by its owner. Unlike executable *binaries*, executable *scripts* should also be *readable* by the user who executes them.

That should be changed to `-rwxr-xr-x` (`chmod 0755`).

---

> My shebang is: `#!/bin/perl`

As already mentioned, that shebang is not portable. Use `#! /usr/bin/perl` instead (and make sure that it's not terminated by `CR/LF`, and it doesn't contain other "invisible" characters, like NULs, BOMs or bidirectional marks ;-)).

Do NOT use `#! /usr/bin/env perl`, as that will open a can of worms; the script will have to be compatible with any wild perl version a user may have in her path, and you will not be able to add any default arguments after `perl` (not even the `--` which should guard against the script being invoked via a symlink which start with a dash).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's a path issue from one box to the other

run `which perl` on the ubuntu box, do the same on the debian box.

as well run `echo $PATH` on both boxes.

Try running it with the full path to perl.